# How do you find the coordinates of the bounding box for meituan Yolov6?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to track a runner in a frame and eventually output velocity of the runner. The way that I am trying to do this is by finding the midpoint of the bounding box and then calculate the change of the midpoint x value over time. My main issue is the where to start or what code to modify in order to have it write the coordinates to a file. Ideally, I want this to work for a video, but I'm assuming it's the same process for a bounding box of a picture, so if anyone has any advice or resources that'd be much appreiciated.